# How to do a subform with all visitors with id_visitors, which is placed in textbox

Tags: sql, ms-access, textbox, adp

I have a little Access program, where i have few tables. I do a form, where i can see one by one all Client, and i do a subform where is information, what Client done. I want to see only information about selected Client, not about all.

The problem is that I NEED TO DO IT in old .adp format. In accdb everything worked perfectly, but in .adp, Stored Procedure give me all information.

How to filter it to see only information about only one visitor?

[image: Image with problem]

I want to see only information about Client with ID=14

Comment: Is subform Master/Child Links properties set?

Comment: Yes. I read on some forums that Links is not working with Stored Procedure,which im using ;/

Comment: What do Master/Child Links properties of subform container have to do with a Stored Procedure? Filter the main form and subform should synchronize. Sorry, I really know nothing about adp.

Comment: So maybe you know how to set variable with value from TextBox in MS Access? if you know, then i can do a Stored Procedure with param and send the id in param, so it will be filtered on start

Comment: In regular MS Access query parameter can reference textbox. I have no idea how a Stored Procedure would work. Setting a variable requires this to happen in some event, like form Load or a button Click.

Comment: Dynamical changing of form RecordSource is one way, but too complicated IMHO. Other way is to use temp tables. Create in database a table, that stores only one value - current client number. After that create a query, that selects data due to value in this temp table. So this query could be used as recordsource for your details form. This limits multi-user using of ADP file, but you have not mentioned needs of multi-user workaround?

Comment: I think about this, but i cant add new Table ;/ i know how to set variable with value from Textbox in VBA, but i dont know how to execute Stored Procedure in VBA ;/ or maybe you know how to set global variable, which will be my parameter to send into Procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather apply filter to subform, addressing to field in master form in this case. And then lock filter for editing by user